# Conditional Update on patition

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to update a table with this logic: lookup for a row which a filter field = 'some value', lets call this "selected row", then update the "selected row" itself and the rows which order field is > of the selected row order field:

for example I want to increase all the prices rows having prices value > of "selected row" price value and the same id_product, where the "selected row" has the distance value = to 7 So selected row is *, udated rows should be ^

```
mytable
id | price | id_product | distance
1  |  10   |   1        |  1        
2  |  04   |   1        |  2 
3  |  02   |   1        |  12 
4  |  44   |   1        |  2   ^
5  |  09   |   1        |  1 
6  |  13   |   1        |  7 * ^
7  |  15   |   1        |  8   ^
8  |  09   |   2        |  5 
9  |  12   |   2        |  8
10 |  17   |   2        |  1  
11 |  32   |   2        | 13  
12 |  22   |   2        |  2
```

Database is postgres 9.2.

Thank you

it was my fault,

```
set price = x.price + 2
```

was wrong, updated to

```
set price = tbla.price + 2
```

.

Adjusted the filter this way:

```
((tbla.price > x.price) OR (x.id = tbla.id AND tbla.price = x.price)) AND x.id_product = tbla.id_product
```

the query works now:

```
UPDATE mytable tbla set price = tbla.price + 2 
FROM ( 
     SELECT price, id, id_product FROM mytable WHERE distance = 7) x 
WHERE ((tbla.price > x.price) OR (x.id = tbla.id AND tbla.price = x.price)) AND x.id_product = tbla.id_product
```

thanks

Comment: What have you already tried? It should be a simple `SELECT` with a `sub-query`.

Comment: tried this 

update mytable tbla set price = x.price + 2 FROM ( SELECT price, id, id_product FROM mytable WHERE distance = 7) x WHERE (x.id = tbla.id OR tbla.price > x.price) AND x.id_product = tbla.id_product

it doesn't work because "selected row" do not get updated. If i use >= operator it gets updated and all the rows with same price, that is unwanted

Comment: Can you please post your query into your post and format it?

Comment: May be I was too quick to state that it's simple.

Comment: @PM77-1: it is simple, the OP just needs to integrate the fact that SQL manipulates sets, rather than elements of a giant array (as his current query is doing). OP: no need for a sub query here; look up the update syntax, and join the table with itself.

Comment: Denis, would you please give more details on how build this query? I have a limited knowledge about sql, would you also give me a link where such strategies are explained. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try to discover a SELECT query that retrieves rows that should be updated, for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable m
JOIN mytable m1
ON m.id_product = m1.id_product
   AND m.price >= m1.price
   AND m1.distance = 7
;
```

then update rows returned by this query:

```
UPDATE mytable SET price = price + 2
WHERE id IN (
   SELECT m.id
   FROM mytable m
   JOIN mytable m1
   ON m.id_product = m1.id_product
      AND m.price >= m1.price
      AND m1.distance = 7
);
```

A demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/f5d59/4

For the sake of clarity, the query in the demo updates an additional column `new_price` instead of `price`:

```
UPDATE mytable SET new_price = price + 2 .....
```